# Perimeter of ellipse: Combination of two geometries

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, plane-geometry

Is there  a  Riemannian  metric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$  such that for every  ellipse $\gamma$ in the plane we have:$$\text{The Euclidien perimeter of}\; \gamma=\lambda (g\text{-diameter of}\;\gamma)$$  for  a  universal constant $\lambda$?

Note that the $g\text{-diameter }$ is the diameter of the interior of the ellipse as  a  metric space with metric induced by riemannian metric $g$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, because otherwise we will have this property also for degenerate ellipses, which are intervals, which would imply that the euclidean distance between two (sufficiently close) 
 points  is $\lambda(g$-distance$)$ which implies that $g$ generated  an euclidean distance and is therefore a flat metric.

Comment: Thank you  very much  for your very interesting  answer.

Comment: Can a similar argument be applied for the following question: Is there a metric $g$ such that every Euclidien ellipse is  a $g$-circle?

Comment: No, since the stereographic projection sends euclidean circles to the circles on the round sphere.